# Should QueryClient stay inside a state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-query

I'm writing a web app with NextJS and TanStack Query

I tried both these ways and I can't see any difference

[image]

[image]

Is there any difference between these two ways of initialise QueryClient instance ?
Which one in the best and why ?

Answer (score 0):

According to clean code principles, you should go with the second option. The main reason is dedicated to SOLID principles, especially the first one which is solid - "a class should only have one responsibility". In your case, you are able to isolate `queryClient`

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/ssr) clearly mention how you should do this with nextJs:

> Create a new QueryClient instance inside of your app, and on an instance ref (or in React state). This ensures that data is not shared between different users and requests, while still only creating the QueryClient once per component lifecycle.